# Is "it is ＋adj. ＋n."used correctly in grammar?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, sentence-usage

> I think it's important what he was doing when he wrote this
> guidebook.

Is this sentence correct? If not, how to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a declarative sentence in English, the subject needs to come before the verb. So, unlike Spanish, for example, we don't say "**it's important something**" in English. The correct usage is "**something is important**."

> I think what he was doing when he wrote this guidebook is important.